# SSRS Returning wrong values for calculated field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I am simply trying to divide a cost by a count from a pregrouped view. It worked fine for me with a different view, but this one is displaying numbers that are all over the place. Any insight would be much appreciated.

[SSRS Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z59Lf.png)

Thank you

[SSRS Tablix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpWxU.png)

Comment: What is the expression you are using? Are Cost and ID Number of Leads fields in your dataset?

Comment: I am doing: =CDbl(Fields!COST.Value)/CDbl(Fields!ID_Number_of_leads.Value)

I originally was not converting, but the numbers were just as off.

Comment: Check if you have groups in you tablix, also double check the expression used in Cost and ID Number of Leads it shuld not be using aggregations.

Comment: I have a parent group - Teams that has a child group - Agents. I want to calculate the cost per lead for each agent. I know for a fact that there are no aggregations within the calculated field. Thanks

Comment: It seems the `Team` and `Agent` groups is causing that behaviour, could you add a screenshot of your tablix in the design view?

Comment: I have added the picture to the post. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you have a column group, however try using: `=SUM(Fields!COST.Value) / SUM(Fields!ID_Number_of_leads.Valu‌​e)` it should work.

Comment: Even without the group defined, the math is still wrong. Super frustrating

Comment: Share with us a sample dataset and your expected result.

Comment: Here is what I want to recreate. This is using the same exact view in SSRS as I am using within an excel pivot table. I am unable to get as far as calculating the cost per lead. 

http://imgur.com/IhZ5ND8

Comment: I think the problem is the context where you are placing the expression. Try deleting the tablix and creating a new one only with the team and Loan_Officer groups. Then use the expression I posted in previous comment.

Comment: When I put aggregates in the calculated fields, the preview fails and says that I cannot use aggregate functions in a calculated field.

For the record, I REALLY appreciate your help.

Comment: Delete the calculated field you are trying to create in the dataset properties, In SSRS you cannot use aggregation functions like SUM in calculated field expression. Those calculation must be perfomed in the report itself.

Comment: You are the man, sir. Thank you so much. It doesn't make any sense to me as to why you can define an aggregate expression in the report itself, but not in a calculated field. Anyway, I'm happy that it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!!!

Delete the calculated field you are trying to create in the dataset properties, In SSRS you cannot use aggregation functions like SUM in calculated field expression. Those calculation must be perfomed in the report itself. – alejandro zuleta